# Setup Print Server Using CUPS?

Tags: wireless, dell, printing

I have recently acquired an old Dell Dimenion 2400 which I hope to use as a print server. My goal is to hook it up to an old HP Inkjet printer and be able to print anywhere in the house via IP. What would be the best method for accomplishing this goal?

Answer (score 1):

You will find guidance on how to setup a CUPS server, which you can find on the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/cups.html). Hope that helps.